# List of floats on the google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Been hunting for an hour or so. It would appear that db.Float does not exist. Is there any way to store a list of floats in a ListProperty? Here's the basic idea:

```
class Data(db.Model):
    temperatures = db.ListProperty(item_type=???)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [FloatProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#FloatProperty) but that has nothing to do with `ListProperty`'s first argument, which, and I quote, is just "a Python type or class" (and `float` is explicitly listed [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Datastore_Value_Types) as a perfectly OK value type, too).  IOW,

```
temperatures = db.ListProperty(float)
```

should work just fine (`float` is a Python built-in identifier, of course).  What problems are you seeing when you do that?